# How to find bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am currently looking at the question:

Let $$A =\begin{bmatrix}
          1& −1& 3& 1& 2\\       
          4& −4& 12& 6& 0\\       
         −3& 3& −9& −4& −2\end{bmatrix}$$

By bringing the matrix A into row echelon form, ﬁnd bases for row(A), col(A) and N(A). Determine the rank and nullity of A, and verify that the Rank-Nullity Theorem holds for the above matrix A.

I have attained that matrix $A$ in row echelon form is

$$ \begin{bmatrix}1 &-1& 3& 1& 2\\ 
 0 & 0& 0& 1& -4\\ 
 0 & 0& 0& 0& 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Do I have to continue where I put the matrix into reduced row echelon form?
Furthermore, I understand how to find $\text{row}(A)$, $\text{col}(A)$ as well as $N(A)$, but how would I find the basis of these? I am struggling to understand the concept of basis and its use

Comment: What have you found for N(A)?

Comment: for N(A), I have { alpha ( 1,1,0,0,0)^T, beta (-3,0,1,0,0)^T, delta (2,0,0,-4,1)^T : alpha,beta,delta belonging to R}

Answer (score 1):

We don’t  need to proceed further, note also that

- a basis for $col(A)$ is given be the first and fourth vectors of the original matrix (corresponding to pivot columns in RREF)
- a basis for $row(A)$ is given by the two rows in the RREF
- to find the null space solve the system $Ax=0$ using A in RREF; since it has dimension 3 the basis is made of three vectors

Comment: Therefore I would have to get the matrix into reduced row echelon form according to your bullet points? Also are your points applicable to all basis questions, if so, why?

Comment: By RREF we can establish the dimension of Col(A) = dimension of Row(A) and by rank nullity theorem the dimension of N(A).

Comment: Moreover by RREF we can select immediately a basis for $Col(A)$ and $Row(A)$ as described in the answer and also solve the system $Ax=0$ to find $N(A)$.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that row(A)= span( (1,-1,3,1,2)^T,(0,0,0,1,-4)^T,(0,0,0,0,0)^T) = {x(1,-1,3,1,2)^T, y(0,0,0,1,-4)^T, z(0,0,0,0,0)^T : x,y,x belonging to R} = {(x, -x, 3x, x+y, 2x-4y : x,y belonging to R} has basis {(1,-1,3,0,-2)^T,(0,0,0,1,-4)}

Comment: Row(A) is the span of the first two rows of A in RREF or also in the original form, both set are bases for Row(A) which has indeed dimension 2.

Comment: As my answer use row echelon for would it be correct?

Comment: Yes use RREF for Row(A) is correct since row operations don’t change row space.